# Проблема с потоками C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Пытаюсь выполнить вычисления с большим количеством матриц, хочу распараллелить вычисления на 4 потока, для чего делаю следующее:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bw1.DoWork += Bw1_DoWork;
        bw2.DoWork += Bw2_DoWork;
        bw3.DoWork += Bw3_DoWork;
        bw4.DoWork += Bw4_DoWork;

        bw1.RunWorkerCompleted += Bw1_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bw2.RunWorkerCompleted += Bw2_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bw3.RunWorkerCompleted += Bw3_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bw4.RunWorkerCompleted += Bw4_RunWorkerCompleted;

        bw1.RunWorkerAsync();
        bw2.RunWorkerAsync();
        bw3.RunWorkerAsync();
        bw4.RunWorkerAsync();

        while (g!=4)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

        result = summ(summ(a1,a2),summ(a3,a4));

        /*вывод результата*/
    }

    private static int g = 0;
    private static int[,] result = new int[indSize, perSize];

   private static void Bw4_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        g++;
    }

    private static void Bw3_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        g++;
    }

    private static void Bw2_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        g++;
    }

    private static void Bw1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        g++;
    }

    private static void Bw4_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
         partialCounta4(0, (int)Math.Pow(2, n * n) / 4);
    }

    private static void Bw3_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
         partialCounta3((int)Math.Pow(2, n * n) / 4, (int)Math.Pow(2, n * n) / 2);
    }

    private static void Bw2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
         partialCounta2((int)Math.Pow(2, n * n) / 2, 3 * (int)Math.Pow(2, n * n) / 4);
    }

    private static void Bw1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        partialCounta1(3 * (int)Math.Pow(2, n * n) / 4, (int)Math.Pow(2, n * n));
    }

    private static int[,] a1 = new int[indSize,perSize];
    private static int[,] a2 = new int[indSize, perSize];
    private static int[,] a3 = new int[indSize, perSize];
    private static int[,] a4 = new int[indSize, perSize];

    private static BackgroundWorker bw1 = new BackgroundWorker();
    private static BackgroundWorker bw2 = new BackgroundWorker();
    private static BackgroundWorker bw3 = new BackgroundWorker();
    private static BackgroundWorker bw4 = new BackgroundWorker();
```

Проблема состоит в том, что при каждом запуске получаются разные результаты, хотя вычисление конечного результата `result` вроде бы должно происходить после завершения всех потоков. `while g!=4` костыль, для того чтобы совершить действие после завершения всех четырех потоков. Как сделать чтобы потоки работали верно?

Comment: вы уверены что Bw*_DoWork завершаются корректно и в RunWorkerCompleted нет ошибок в e.Error?

Comment: @S.Kost в DoWorkEventArgs нет Error, зато он есть в RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs, и да, там действительно есть ошибки. Не совсем правда понятно, почему он на них не вылетает, и почему соответственно выдает какой-то результат, к тому же каждый раз разный

Comment: а какая ошибка в e.Error?

Comment: @S.Kost OutOfRangeException, т.е. ошибка в моем коде обработчике. Буду разбираться. Нет ли у вас комментариев по поводу качества такого подхода? Как можно сделать лучше?

Comment: смотреть в сторону async/await. Использовать метод Task.WhenAll. А так, я бы сделал проверку в каждом RunWorkerCompleted, если g==4, то посчитать result. Так не придется использовать while(g!=4)

Comment: А что именно делается с матрицами? Дело в том, что с матрицами большого размера огромное значение имеет правильное использование процессорного кэша. Например, специальный алгоритм перемножения матриц, эффективно использующий кэш, даёт ускорение примерно в 4 раза без всякой многопоточности. А вычисления в несколько потоков, наоборот, могут вымывать данные из кэша.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы порекомендовал почитать что-то по основам многопоточного и параллельного программирования. Можно начать [со статей Албахари](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) (часть из них [здесь](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2013/10/articles.html#albahari)) или с его книги "C# 6.0 in a Nutshell".

Если очень кратко, то тут нужно понимать пониятия гонок и атомарности.

Например, недетерминизм вашего результата заключается в том, что вы увеличиваете значение глобальной перемеррой `g` из разных потоков. Но операция `g++` - это составная операция, которая выглядит так: `g = g + 1`. Эта операция не атомарна, поскольку вначале нужно прочитать значение, а потом его сохранить.

Когда более чем один поток выполняют эту операцию, то в результате можно легко потерять один инкремент:

```
Поток 1: читает g
Поток 2: читает g
Поток 1: прибавляет 1 и сохраняет результат в g
Поток 2: прибавляет 1 и сохраняет результат в g
```

В результате, если вначале `g` было равно 0, то после 2-х "одновременных" инкрементов, вместо 2-х, `g` будет равняться 1.

Чтобы избежать конкретно этой проблемы нужно использовать `Interlocked.Increment`, но вообще, для решения вашей задачи, нужно разбить пространство решения задачи на независимые кусочки, и использовать один поток для каждой задачи.

Насколько я помню, на сайте pluralsight в основе многопоточности в .NET используются похожие примеры. Если есть доступ, посмотрите.